# How to make pip install to PATH on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I installed [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) via `pip`, but when I try to run it I get `pyinstaller: command not found`
After installation of the package the following warning was displayed:

```
WARNING: The scripts pyi-archive_viewer, pyi-bindepend, pyi-grab_version, pyi-makespec, pyi-set_version and pyinstaller are installed in '/home/kevinapetrei/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Do you know how can I make it so `pip` installs everything straight to `PATH`?

Comment: The better practice is adding `$HOME/.local/bin` to your PATH, instead of trying to change what pip does.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Same way you make any other change to your PATH -- edit `~/.bash_profile` if you have one, or `~/.profile`, etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rather than messing with existing entires in `PATH`, consider appending to it the location from **pip**.

It usually is `~/.local/bin` (consistent with [systemd's file-hierarchy](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#Home%20Directory)).

Good place to add/modify environmental variables is `~/.profile` file.
You do it by adding the following line:

```bash
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

You may also consider `~/.pam_environment` (but it has slightly different syntax).

---

For those wondering about the actual answer to the question:
It used to be somewhat possible in old versions of Python 3, but the option got patched away.

Comment: The `export` here isn't needed: Changes to a variable that's already in the environment are automatically exported back to the environment.

Comment: Why do I have to do `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` everytime I have a new terminal?

Comment: Have you added this to `~/.profile` file or ant other configuration file of your shell of choice?

Comment: Im new to linux so I'm confused haha. How do I do that? I just entered `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` into the terminal.

Comment: @OzonePrograms, see [How to permanently set environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) on our sister site [unix.se].

Comment: Yeah... the only problem is that I have no idea how to really follow those instructions haha.

Comment: Open file `.profile` from your home directory, paste the line, save and it's done.

Comment: How do I find `.profile`? I go in home but there is no .profile

Comment: Files starting with dot are hidden files, so you may just not see it. And if it really doesn't exist, then just create it.

Comment: ...well, that depends. If you already have a `.bash_profile`, then bash will ignore `.profile`, so you'll want to either edit the contents of `.bash_profile`, or make sure that it acts to include `.profile` when both exist.

Comment: Either way, though, it's a better question for [unix.se] than here, not being specifically about writing software and more about how to configure your operating system as an end-user.

Comment: I enabled hidden files and I found .profile let me try to paste it in now.

Comment: I pasted `PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` into `.profile` but `pyinstaller` is still `command not found` do I need to restart my PC?

Comment: You at least need to restart terminal. And read what Charles commented